# Swift: How to deal with method overloads where only the return type differs and the result is discardable?

Tags: ios, swift, methods, overloading

this is my first question and I hope you guys can help me out.

Lets assume I've written a Framework in Swift that does stuff purely with native Swift Types. This is our interface:

```swift
class Foo {
    @discardableResult
    public func perform(query: String) -> [String: Any]? {
        return [:]
    }
}
```

Note that our result is discardable.

I would now like to support other Libraries optionally. I know we have Codable and stuff but lets assume that I want to support SwiftyJSON optionally by creating an extension that only compiles when SwiftyJSON can be imported.

```swift
#if canImport(SwiftyJSON)

import SwiftyJSON

extension Foo {
    @discardableResult
    func perform(query: String) -> JSON? {
        // Call internal func => cast JSON => return JSON
        return JSON()
    }
}

#endif
```

Without SwiftyJSON (can not import) this compiles:

```swift
let bar = Foo().perform(query: "")
```

With SwiftyJSON it does not because its ambiguous.
Return type has to be explicitly defined like:

```swift
let baz: [String: Any]? = Foo().perform(query: "")
// or
let bar: JSON? = Foo().perform(query: "")
```

For calls where I want the result thats fine.
BUT: Since we have a discardableResult calls like

```swift
Foo().perform(query: "")
```

will always be ambiguous.

The following calls work but are not very nice imho.

```swift
Foo().perform(query: "") as JSON?
Foo().perform(query: "") as [String: Any]?
```

What is the best way to deal with this problem? Should the method just not be overloaded and have a different name instead? Or am I overlooking something that makes the calls non ambiguous in a nice way?

Edit:

A comment suggested to remove discardableResult. I really do not wanna do that since that would lead to a lot of calls that look like this:

```swift
_ = Foo().perform(query: "")
```

The more I think about the problem it occurs to me that there might just not be a good solution for this..

Comment: You have two functions with the same name and different signatures (String) ->[String: Any]? and (String)->JSON? so the only way to tell them apart is the return value but with discardableResult you say it can be ignored. For me it looks like the easiest solution is to remove discardableResult

Comment: Use an else clause. You don’t need both.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, removing `@discardableResult` wouldn't work, and `_ = Foo().perform(query: "")` wouldn't compile, it would still have the same ambiguity: it's not that the compiler is being nitpicky, but it has *literally no way of knowing which of your two functions to call!*

It might be interesting to think about what behavior you'd expect from this line, and why.

You seem to want to have a function based on an existing function which:

1. Returns a different type;
2. Has the same name and parameters;
3. Has a discardable result.

Unfortunately, it looks like it's a classic "pick any two" type of scenario…

Well, let's do just that! Let's see what happens if we stop insisting on any one of the three conditions.

Let me use a simpler example:

```
@discardableResult func doSomething() -> String {
    return "a"
}

@discardableResult func doSomething() -> Int {
    return 1
}

doSomething() // won't compile
let x:String
x = doSomething() // "a"
```

We have a function overloaded with two return types (`String` and `Int`), and we see that we cannot discard its result as it would result in unresolvable ambiguity.

#### 1. Single return type: use an enum with a payload

Let's eliminate the first condition, and try using a single return type. This is possible:

```
enum ReturnType {
    case text(_ payload:String)
    case number(_ payload:Int)
}

@discardableResult func doSomething() -> ReturnType {
    if ... // some condition
    {
        return .text("a")
    } else {
    return .number(1)
    }
}

doSomething() // works
let x = doSomething() // ReturnType.text("a") or ReturnType.number(1)
```

Here we cannot (easily) extend the functionality via extensions; rather, we'd need to touch the enum and function code with all the possible options every time we want to add a new return type. (Of course advanced APIs can also be created that help third parties easily write extensions… If it's worth the effort.)

We would also need a way to determine which return type to choose: it can be a function parameter, or a value stored elsewhere, etc. Here's an example with a parameter:

```
@discardableResult func doSomething(useText:Bool = false) -> ReturnType {
    if useText {
        return .text("a")
    } else {
    return .number(1)
    }
}

doSomething() // works
doSomething(useText:true) // works
let x = doSomething() // ReturnType.number(1)
let x2 = doSomething(useText:false) // ReturnType.number(1)
let x3 = doSomething(useText:true) // ReturnType.text("a")
```

**Note**: Here, we lose the convenience of having the compiler infer the type from the call site; since the type is now an opaque wrapper, it's no longer the compiler's business to make sure that the wrapped type is correct. This may be a high cost for simply maintaining "result discardability," but then it may also allow us to abstract away some details, only unwrapping the "payload" when needed, which can have its own benefits.

#### 2. Change the name or parameters of the function

This is quite easy:

```
@discardableResult func doSomething() -> String {
    return "a"
}

@discardableResult func doSomethingElse() -> Int {
    return 1
}

doSomething() // works
doSomethingElse() // works
let x = doSomething() // "a"
let y = doSomethingElse() // 1
```

We can also use this in an extension. All we lose is the shared name.

Changing the parameters is also possible but it would be pretty silly in this already-silly example:

```
@discardableResult func doSomething() -> String {
    return "a"
}

@discardableResult func doSomething(thinkOfAnyNumber:Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

doSomething() // "a"
doSomething(thinkOfAnyNumber:42) // 1
```

**Note:** I'd obviously only do this if the additional parameters actually make sense.

**Note 2:** The parameter *configuration* is different between the two functions, not the parameter *values* like in the previous case.

#### 3. Do not make the result discardable

Note that simply removing the `@discardableResult` attribute won't make it *impossible* to try to discard the result: you'll still be able to try the `_ =` assignment, or simply ignore the function result (and the compiler warning). Both will ultimately fail to compile, so it will be up to the user of the API to avoid doing either.

Hopefully, your function does some other things (side effects) than provide a return value: in that case, there may be little use in discarding the result of a function that does nothing but provide that result, and one may probably be better off not calling it in the first place.

If the side effects are identical between the two overloaded functions, you can factor them out into a single function:

```
func doTheActualWork() {
    // ...
}

func doSomething() -> String {
    doTheActualWork()
    return "a"
}

func doSomething() -> Int {
    doTheActualWork()
    return 1
}

doSomething() // won't compile
doTheActualWork() // use this instead
let z:String = doSomething() // "a"
```

Note that this can also be done via extensions as long as they re-use existing functions and only overload them with different signatures and/or return types.

Now if the side effects (i.e. `doTheActualWork()` implementations) are also different in the two cases… Then I give up. But that can be handled as well.

Well, this is what I've been able to gather on this interesting problem. Now I may be dead wrong, and there may be something better out there… We'll find out soon enough.